# In SCSS automatically switch direction of linear gradient for webkit prefix

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I've finally bitten the bullet and started using SCSS. Why didn't I do this sooner? Anyway, throughout the project I'm using horizontal linear gradients and so I have created this mixin:

```
@mixin linear-gradient($direction,$left-color,$right-color) {
  background: $left-color; // For browsers that do not support gradients
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient($direction,$left-color,$right-color); // Safari 5.1-6 note direction is opposite
  background: -o-linear-gradient($direction,$left-color,$right-color); // Opera 11.1-12
  background: -moz-linear-gradient($direction,$left-color,$right-color); // Fx 3.6-15
  background: linear-gradient(to $direction,$left-color,$right-color); // Standard
}
```

This works a treat, however, you will notice that the webkit prefixed line simply uses **$direction**. When, in fact, it should be the opposite of the direction specified in order to get a consistent result. So where *left* is specified in the webkit line, the direction is actually *right*.

I've seen much more complex ways of applying a total solution to background gradients, but this seems unnecessary for my project.

Can someone tell me how to properly write something like an @if @else statement which automatically converts the direction from left to right or vice-versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a `@mixin` then you need some `if / else` statement (you can use shorthand `if`). But maybe that's a right time to go further and take a look at [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer)? Then you can write pure `CSS` and the script will take care of browser support for you! :)

UPDATE:

If you want to cover only `left` / `right` directions you might do it like this:

```
@mixin linear-gradient($direction, $left-color, $right-color) {
  $legacy-direction: if($direction == left, right, left);
  background: $left-color; // For browsers that do not support gradients
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient($legacy-direction, $left-color, $right-color); // Safari 5.1-6 note direction is opposite
  background: -o-linear-gradient($legacy-direction, $left-color, $right-color); // Opera 11.1-12
  background: -moz-linear-gradient($legacy-direction, $left-color, $right-color); // Fx 3.6-15
  background: linear-gradient(to $direction, $left-color, $right-color); // Standard
}
```

If you want to cover all the possibilities (`top`, `bottom` and diagonal like `top right`) then it's a bit more complex. Here you have an example solution: https://gist.github.com/ykhs/3690526

Comment: Thanks for the response @norin89, I guess what I'm looking for is a specific answer on how to write the if/else to work with my example. I know I need something that says _if direction is left, then display right_. I'm just unsure how to write this. I'll take a look at autoprefixer, sounds promising.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for:
`$legacy-direction: if($direction == left, right, left);`

Thank you so much @norin89.